# Windows 8 Display Resolution exceptions for multiple monitors

Tags: windows-8

With the [minimum requirement for Windows 8 being 1024x768](https://web.archive.org/web/20151114195415/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8/archive/2011/10/20/optimizing-for-both-landscape-and-portrait.aspx), does that mean that the main monitor must be this large, and we can still plug in [smaller 7" monitors running 800x480](https://web.archive.org/web/20130926121718/http://lilliputweb.net/index.php?Controller=User_Product&action=ShowProduct&product_id=103)?  Or does that mean *all* devices must support the higher resolution?

I would love to snap the Netflix app down to a small monitor and free up my other monitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From reading this page it looks like you can use smaller monitors and there are a number of ways of getting it working:

http://www.clickonf5.org/14830/windows-8-metro-style-apps-running-on-low-screen-resolution-netbooks/

---

One way is to attach another monitor.

Another is to enable DownScaling, restart, then increase the resolution:

> Locate the following location in Registry window,
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E
> 968-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E
> 968-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0001
>
> In both of these locations, find
> “Display1_DownScalingSupported” in the DWORD list
> Right-click on the
> DWORD and select modify, change the value from 0 to 1 for that DWORD

Comment: Will this work in the RTM?

Comment: I can't test it at the moment unfortunately.

Comment: I started to test this, but things are different in my RTM system.  First of all, I have a Display1_DownScalingSupported and a Display2_DownScalingSupported, and I'm not sure which to change (I would want to test my secondary monitor, Display2?).  Secondly, I don't have any xxx_DownScalingSupported in the 0001 section.  So with those two issues, I'm concerned about making this edit.

Comment: It might vary depending on PC/laptop/displays as well as CTP and RTM. Suggest we wait for someone who can confirm.

Comment: From this page http://liliputing.com/2010/03/hack-to-increase-the-screen-resolution-on-windows-7-netbooks.html it looks like this has existed since windows 7 though, so I doubt it changed between CTP and RTM, maybe it just varies depending on the setup of the machine. This page, http://www.tlbhd.com/how-to-get-better-resolution-on-your-standard-10-inch-netbook-2772/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+netbooklive+(Netbooklive.net+-+all+you+need+to+know+about+netbooks)&utm_content=Google+Reader says to simply search and replace all key values.